# Use dot notation for accessing SVG attributes?

Tags: javascript, svg

Normally when I modify SVG element attributes I use the setAttribute method like this:

```
var rectSecond_current = document.getElementById( "rect3" );
rect3.setAttribute( "fill", "bisque" );
```

However, I see that sometimes dot notation can be used. For example:

```
createPath( svgCanvas, "vcrGoBegin", ul_x, ul_y, pathGoBegin, 1, 
    "orangered", "orange", 1, 0 );
vcrGoBegin.addEventListener( "click", function(){
    begin();
}, false );
```

Is there a way to use dot notation to access attributes, like the x/y location of the element?

Comment: what do you mean by _dot notation_?

Comment: Using a dot to access a property. Look at the code example.

Comment: it depends on the attrib, and any attrib with a JS reserved name will need an alias name or a setAttribute call. you can explore the "Properties" of each element in dev tools. typically though, there are mappings from the property to the attrib, at least for the important/common ones.

Comment: In both snippets no attribute of an SVG element is accessed using dot notation. What did you have in mind?